# got error while trying to remove query from QueryStore

Tags: sql-query-store

I was tring to remove a slowquery from QueryStore, but I got an error message saying:

> query can't be deleted as there is an active forcing policy on this queryid while executing "sp_query_store_remove_query @queryid"

Can't we remove the query in this case?

I tried `exec sp_query_store_remove_query @queryid`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ALTER DATABASE WideWorldImporters SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR;
```

Comment: this removes all Data from QueryStore, we are trying to list out and remove queries that are taking more time to execute.